# selecting the top 3 values in a column (brands)with highest average list price - SQL Query Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

Need help in a query for the following,

***What are the top three brands with the highest average list price? and the top three categories?***

The database has 3 tables :-

1. products
   [Products Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWGx2.png)
2. brands [Brands table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opNFU.png)
3. Categories [Categories table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaIzA.png)

Any help would be appreciated

**Note: products table has 33 rows so could not give the whole table here.**

Comment: sample data in consumable format and desired output are highly appreciated

Comment: @Sergey I tried to make it as formattable as I could, suggest to me how I can share the tables in the question instead of images.

Comment: DDL and DML is by far the best way, @soheb_kh . Otherwise use a markdown table.

Answer (score 0):

The following queries should give you what you need.

```
--This one is for brands with higher average price
SELECT
TOP 3
P.brand_id,
B.brand_name,
AVG(LIST_PRICE)
FROM products P LEFT OUTER JOIN
brands B ON P.brand_id=B.brand_id
GROUP BY P.brand_id,B.brand_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC

--This one is for categories with higher average price
SELECT
TOP 3
P.category_id,
B.category_name,
AVG(LIST_PRICE)
FROM products P LEFT OUTER JOIN
categories C ON P.category_id=C.category_id
GROUP BY P.category_id,B.category_name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```